# How do I link Google Docs to Trello?

Tags: google-drive, trello

I hear you can now link Google Docs to Trello and I was wondering how to go about this.

Comment: Do you have any link to where you heard this? Or was it word-of-mouth?

Answer (score 2):

There's no formal way to link Google Docs to a Trello card. You could add a URL in a comment or the card description and it will turn it into a link, though.